# Привязка блока в к определённому месту background

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Всем привет
Подскажите есть ли решение привязать блок с видео в определённую часть background. что бы в последующем подставить фон в видео, что бы он пиксель в пиксель въехал в background. (при различных разрешениях экрана)

Надеюсь кто-то понял о чём я)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На картинке выше есть видео с пандами в которое я позже подставлю фон. мне нужно что бы при изменении ширины браузера видео тоже масштабировалось и было в тех же координатах

Comment: есть пример? так не очень понятно

Comment: видео в iframe вставлять будете?

Comment: нет
<video src></video>

Answer (score 1):

Позиционируете блок с видео абсолютно, задав `left` и `top` так, чтобы совпало с фоном. Повторяете процедуру для разных разрешений экрана с помощью медиа-запросов.

Если вас угораздило сделать `background-posiition` зависящим от размера экрана (например, `top center` или `7% 30%`), вам придется этими же процентами и позиционировать (возможно, вовсю применяя `calc()`.

```css
.vidos {
  width:320px;
  height:180px;
  box-shadow:0 0 10px 2px #000 inset;
  position: absolute;
  top:50px;
  left:50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
  text-align:center;
}

.fon {
width:100%;
height:300px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position: top center;
position:relative;
background-image:url('data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEBLAEsAAD/4QBmRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgABAEaAAUAAAABAAAAPgEbAAUAAAABAAAARgEoAAMAAAABAAIAAAExAAIAAAAQAAAATgAAAAAAAAEsAAAAAQAAASwAAAABcGFpbnQubmV0IDQuMS42AP/bAEMAHBQVGRUSHBkXGSAeHCIrRy4rJycrVz5CNEdnW21rZVtkYnKApItyeZt7YmSOwpCbqa63ubduicnXx7LWpLS3sP/bAEMBHiAgKyUrVC4uVLB1ZHWwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsLCwsP/AABEIAXcDIAMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAfAAABBQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAQIDBAUGBwgJCgv/xAC1EAACAQMDAgQDBQUEBAAAAX0BAgMABBEFEiExQQYTUWEHInEUMoGRoQgjQrHBFVLR8CQzYnKCCQoWFxgZGiUmJygpKjQ1Njc4OTpDREVGR0hJSlNUVVZXWFlaY2RlZmdoaWpzdHV2d3h5eoOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4eLj5OXm5+jp6vHy8/T19vf4+fr/xAAfAQADAQEBAQEBAQEBAAAAAAAAAQIDBAUGBwgJCgv/xAC1EQACAQIEBAMEBwUEBAABAncAAQIDEQQFITEGEkFRB2FxEyIygQgUQpGhscEJIzNS8BVictEKFiQ04SXxFxgZGiYnKCkqNTY3ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqCg4SFhoeIiYqSk5SVlpeYmZqio6Slpqeoqaqys7S1tre4ubrCw8TFxsfIycrS09TV1tfY2dri4+Tl5ufo6ery8/T19vf4+fr/2gAMAwEAAhEDEQA/ANKlpBS9a6TlCilopDExS0UUAFIRn606igCOlpxHem0xBimsuR70+igLENFPdcc9qbiquTYSilxRQKw2lxS0YoCw2inUYoCw2inUYoCw2lHWlxRQAYopaKQxKKWigBKeOlNpy9KGNBRS0UhiUoooHWgAopcUUAJRS0uKAG0U6kxQAlIetOpKAEopaKAEpp60+m0xCYpKdRQIbS4paKAGmkpT1oxTATFGKWigQlGKWigYmKMUtGKAExRilooATFFLS0ANxRinYooAbTgMfWlA70tK47CUUtFIBAMnFPAxSgYFLSuUkJRS0UAJRilxRigBMUUtMPNACHn6UmKdiimIbijFOpp5piGnmjFOxRigQ3FGKdiimFhuKMU7FGKAsNxRinYoxSCw3FGKdRTCw3FGKdRSCw3FGKdRimFhuKMU7FFILDcUYp2KMUBYbijFOxS4ouOwtLRRSGKKWkpaQwopaKQwooooAKQinUUAMopSMUUxCVGRg+1W4ygXnGaikCseKSlqNx0IcUYpcUVZAlJinUmKAEopaKAEopaUIxGdpxRcLDaKAyk4zzShSegJouFgFFHeloASilxRQMSlXrRSjrSAWjFLRSGJigdaWigBaMUUUDDFFFGKACiiigAxTadSUCExRilooAaelNp7dKbTEFFLRTASkp1IaAG0UtFAhKKWigBKKWigBKKWigBKXFFLQAlGKWigBKAM0uKdjFA7CUUtFIYlPUY+tCr3p2KkaQlFLRQMSilooATFFKeKaeaBDTzRinYopiG0GlPFNpgJ1oxTqKBDcUYp1FADcUYp1FADcUYp2KMUAJijFLRQAmKMUtFACYoxS0UAJiilooASjFLiloHYbilxS0lABRRRQACloxQKQC0UUUDFFLSU9G2nJqWNDSCOooqV5AwwBUdCGxKWiigQYppFOoxQA2ilopgNZc896ZUtNZcc00yWhlGKWimISilpKAHRKGlUN0qzIRjrVUgjsQaf5ny4YfiKzkr6lp2VivdRhkJXh15BqWzuB5Hz9agmfJKg060VngUhck88UJdxJu+hLI29sgUg6VL9mkx1WoyCrYbrVJrYHF7iUU4qwGSpxSUxCUUtFMQ6igdKWpKEopaKACilooGJRilooASilooAQ0lOPSkoEJRS0UAMbtSU49aSmISilopiEpD1p1JQAlFLRTATFFLRQAmKMUtFIBKKWigAooooAKKWlA70AIBilpaKRQlKBnrSgZp1IAooopFBRRRQAUHig8U2gQnWinKjN0FBUqcEU7hYbQfSgmkpiEopaMUCEpcUU9zGQNgwaVx2GUYpaKYhKKWigYlFLRQAlFLRQAlFLRQAlFLRQAlLS0lABRRRQAUlLSUAFFFFAhcUYpaKBiUooopAFFKKKBiiikpRSAWiiloGJRS0UgEIzSU6kIzTAQAk4HWntFgdaSNtrZ9ae7etYVZtGkI3Khba21hg06mXLBiMdaeAQAD1AxSw9WU7phVgo2aCjocilorqMRXkZ8BscUylooWgDWRXGHGRU0GIoAB0AxUdRSTbCyZGOG5rOpsa0Vd2LLyk96pyyZnUA5K9aaryTZ8vO3+92/CpYoBHz1NZpNnRKUYLUnZ2I2k8U3FA6UtbrQ4hKKWkpiFWnU1etOpDEopaKBijpRSjpRSGJRUqopXmmMAG4pXCw2ilopgIaSlNFAhACTgdaCpU4PFLyDkUjEnJJzQAyiloqhCUUuKKBDTSUp60UwEopaKACiiigAoopcUAJRS0UAJRS0UgADNLS0UDCgDJop4GKQxOlLRRSGFFFFABSHilJxTaBCdaKWimA5JCg9qa7lzTTzRRYLhRRRTEFFFFABRRRQAUUUtACUUtFACUUtJQAUUuKKQCYpaKKBhRRRQAUlLRQISinLt3fN0obbu+TpRcBtFFFMBKKWigBaKWikMSilooASloooAWiilpDAUtJSikMKWiigAooooAQimOrFflb8DUtIRiolFSVmNNx1RUhRmnJdSPL9fU1YYZ5p3eilTgoKyHOTm7sjopxH5UlbGdhtFOxSUAJTDHG7h2RWYcAkZxUmCegJpdjD+E0tAV1sNNJS0VQgHWlpKWkAlFLRQAnen02njoKTGhKKWigYCloFLSASilooGJRS0UANNJSnrRTEJSN0p1NbqKBDaKWimISg0tIaAEoxRRTEFFFFAwopaKAEopaKAEopaKAAKW6DNKBjr1pUZl6GjOTk9aWoxKKWnAUgEAxS0tFIYlFLRQAlB4oJxTaYBRS0hpiCkoooASloowcZwcUCCiiigAooooAKKKKACikopgLSUoFLikAmKVVyQKKKBiuu09c0lFFIBKKWimAlFLRQAlFLSUAFJS0UCEooooAKKKKYD6MUtFSWJRS0UAJiiloxQAlApaKACiilpAKKWm0ooGLRRRSAKKWigBpFIKf1pNjelFwsJTCMVL5belIyHHNFwaIqkij3cnpTKmhPy4705PQUVqSAY4ApaKKzNBjoG6j8arMpVsGrTOq9TUDncqmqi2RJIjpRRQOtaEC0lLRSASnL0pKVetAxaKWikMQdadSDrTsUhiUUtFACUUtFADCOaMUp60YpiEph61JTKaExKKWimISm049KSgBKcjbGzjNJRigAY7mJxikpaKAEoxS0YoEJiloooGFGKKdQAlFLSgUhgBS0tFIYlFLRQAlITilJxTaBDkTceaWRAvQ0zp0NBOe9HUBCaSiiqEFFLRQAlOLsV254pKSgAooooAKKKKBBRThGT7U8Rge9K47EQFLipdq0bBS5h8pFRTyh7U3HrTuAlLRRQIKKKKACkpaKAEooopgFJRRQAUUUUCCkpaSgAooopgSUUUVJoFFFFABRS0UAJRS0UAJRS0UgFopKUGgBRS0lApDFopaKQD1XAz3p1AORRUlBSMNwxS0UhldlxTelWSA3WomiParUiHEaJH9aQux6mneW3pSiE9+KegtSIDccUrcnjoKe+FG1fxNMpoTEopaMUxBRQKWkMSgcEUtJQA+jFLRSGIOtOpKdSGJRS4ooATFFLiigBlFFLTENPQ02nt0ptNCY2lpaKYhppKWjFAhKKWigBKKWigBKKWjFACUUtKBQAgFLS0UhiAU6iloGJRS0UgEpCaU02mAUUUhpiA0lLRQAlFLRTEJRS0lABRRRQAUlLjNOxikA0KTUqoF+tKowPenhPWpci1Eb1pdhqSiouVYZ5Z9RSbDUtJRcdiKkYZFTYz1qKQbQaaZLRDS0UVoQJRRRQAA4OaV3LYzim0lFhC0lFFMAooooAKKKSgQtJRRTAKKKKAJaKWioNRKKWigBKKWigBKKcq7jjtUwAHSpbsOxBtb0NG1vQ1YopcwWK3SirBAPUU0xDtxT5gsRClp3lN7UojPei6CwgVqUjHWpKCM0rjsRg4p2+kK4pKBDwwNOqMZzxTwPWkMKKKKQwooooAhMTdjmk8tvSp6Kq7JsV9jehpMY61ZpCoYc0cwuUrU6gjBIpR0qiRKKkWPPJp2xfSlzFcpGvSlxT9g7UhXFK4WG06kpw6CgBKMUtFAxKD0NLSHpQA2ilopiGN1pKU9TRTEJikPSnUhoENopaKYCUUtFACUUtFACYopaKAExS0uKKQCU4DFKBRQMSjFLRSASkJpTSUwEopaTBPamIQ0U7YaNh9KLhYZRTiCO1JQISilpKYBRS4zTlXNFwsMAJpQKk2H1pNhzxSuOw2lXlqd5Zx70qL81K47D1XuadRRWZoFLSUUALRRSUAFRz9BUlRv96mtxPYgzRTyg7cUgjJPBrS6MrDKKdujD+TuHmHtSbTQpJg0JRSHI7YoALHjmqEFCyKjqGYDdwM9zRg5xjmoLtMeU2cMDketROVlcEWWTAOCSaZUNvcOJsSuWV+OexqbpnPFEJ8w2gop207cn8qbVkhRRRTAKKKKAJqKKKg2FUZNBGDQKXNSOw2ilox707isKhw1S5qvJNDBtMsgTccDPeobK6knnuFYqY0OUIHbNQ2rjL9FR5pc0DH0U3NGaAHUU3cM4yM9cUuaQC0UZozTAWkwKKWkAUUUUAFFFFABSUtFACUUtJQAUhIHU0pGRUZjPrTEMPJJoHWnFCKSqJJqKjBI6UEk9TU2KuSZFLUNSjpQwQ1h3FA6Uo5FJigAooooAKD0ooNADcUtFB6UxDKKXFFMQlJinGkoENoxTqKYCUUtFK4DcUYp1FMBtKKWikAlKBSgUtAxKMUUuKAEpDQaKAEoopKYh4XHXrS0daeFxU3KSGYPpRtNSUUrjsR4PpSFR3FTUmB3ouKxB5foaNmPepiopNpp8wuUi2mnKuKfg0YxyaGx2Db71GzHJVevc+lOaTHAH41Eprjr17K0TRRGzW/nBDvIZOhqaORHOVYGgGoYRx/wIkVnCu0HKi5SU0uqkBjgnpTq7rkjWdVIDMAT0yetK7KilmOAKoSHzXLkewpzPIyFGOQfao5hXFFy7XShf8AVk4wR+tXaz1T50z03CtCnFggpGUN1pGdUGWOBVOV2kfIJVR0AOKblYC0UPaoLl3jUKp2s3celCzyKpB+Y9iaibc7bnOTUud1YRCo2yK3cMDmtAqR2qntq7bMzRfMckHFFN2FYbjPFQSu0LbUxk8nP8qmnYBTsYBs44qtt/E1Up9EFh32k44TDe5yKhcvJguc46VJto21k23uBCAVIbGSDnFWnePaXBBb+7nvTFiLZx25pNtOLcdgsLDIzSMJG4boD2qbyxnBbr2qDbSbB6VUajSFYlZdpxSU4kmNSeoOM02umLurkMKKKKoRPRS0VmbiUhFLSgE9KAGZOaM1Deu6CMRuVJOTtPpTopBKu4lUIOCM1HOr2GUL5jLdMD0j+UVZ0xSFmfCAHA446VXkJkldzjk9qYYwc+/Brn5rSuSa+cdaXkdRWatzOikB8knO4jJHsKdDcFZIw4UDGHfu3ua19oh3NHNGaYQRj39KZLKIE3sOey+taNpajM+8keLU2ljOGUKPqMdK0LW7W6ViFKMp5U1lkPIzOx3MfmY1LaOsE6sw2qylS38jWClqI1t1OyagkkCxblZTngEGqZc9mb/vqrlNIuMWzTyaXNZW5/77/wDfRpGneFTLudtnO3d1/wA81KqeQ3CxrZpc1k3D5vBLG2doG09ulXrefzYS7gLg4PPFUpJuxBYzS5qkl6GnCbMIxwr561azTTT2AfRTM0uaYDqSqg1C2MroZNpTqWGB+FWUkWRA6MGU9CO9FwHUUZozQAU1k7inUUAR4oxUlG0U7isR08ZIpcUtFwCiikxzSGJiilxRimAlIadSGgQlIelOpDQA2ilooENNFLRTASinUlAhKKWigBKKWigBKKXFLQMSilpKAAdaU0lGaAAqQM02pc0wrRcGhlFOop3FYVeMVLUWCaeOBUspC0tNz70bhSuMUsF6kCgEHoajcBse1N2Cp5hDWkfcdp49MVOjB1zUe0UoAU5HWkmBLUMki8Y5weadk+tIPYUpO6sO5XclgSD/APXpFNTNCrHIyp/2ajFuVbImcD0wK4nQm2aqasJJKI0yzBc8DJ6mlhOcbVJGOpGBUf8AZ6PMss8jTFPuhsYH4VYWPa2Vdgv93ORWtOgo6slyWyGmFiclhnOamy3crj6UlFdFzMYIF/vGjyE9Wp+CfYU0qezEGsZVUug+UPJj9D+dPUBFCrwBUYkwdr8Hsexp9axmpK6BqwMA/wB4ZxSeXH/cWlzRmncQbE/uL+VGxP7i/lRmjNFwDan9xfypRhegA+lJmkzRcBdif3F/Kk8uP+4KM0uadwE8qP8Au/rSeTH7/nTs0bqNAG+Qnqw/Gk+zj+8aeD65ozRoAz7P/t/pSeQ3qtSZpc0aARCNwMYBH1pDEeykVNmlzVRlYTimVGBU/MCKTIq5mkKo3VQa0VQnkGUtFFBoJ/KqUjNMcseOy9hV1hwQaj8tP7ornrS6CKewDoKQoO4q75cf92k8qP8Au/rWFxFPbRtq55Uf939aPKj/ALp/OncCltpNtXfJj9D+dHkR/wC1+dFwKgLqu1XZV9AaYVycsST6k5q99nj/ANr86T7NH6t+dO4FN4WQjehx1/ClcRtJ8uUjxwOuK0NjMD87EYx2qH7KnZ3psZUVNi4xgmndqgmuLhLhovJQ4bauSRu96sXYMGwxRPIufm2n7uKp2OhSS0EqG6lSKFWckAtngfgP6003RUDdBKhIOMr1NSiFLuNflyoAID8dP8mjbUJPQdaeUquky5KcL9O3+FK6RZHlkkY53etEabG8yRPlzgk+n+FXJIkkAMbBQeuB1qXqYS3KRGQAScDp7VficmFC33sc1F9mP98flUiiVFCgxtju2adOVnqJEozjOKXJAJwcDmqMlrM8xlEqoxGBtzwKmf7U8ZTdECRjcCQa19ohmXIfOleXbt3nOK0tPdRapGCAwJGD3PXioRYyf3o/zNIbGT/pn+dZqVncRpcjr+dAYMMqQR6is02kxAUkEAYA3nFSQRXFuTsVCp6qWq/aAXqZM/lQvJxlRkZ9acrZUFhtPcdajuCzRFI0D7gQcnGKpyVgK1vftws4yScBlFXJp0gTc5/AdTWf9llxjy/1FILWQH/VfyrNTYGjDOk6bkz1wQeoqXNZ1vDLHOrbSq/xe9X8j1FXGV1qMfRTMj+8KXI9RVXQDqKbkeopcj1FF0AtNpcj1pMj1p3AKKOPWjj2ouISg0uR6ikyPWi6ATFGKXI9aMj1ougEooyKNwpcyAKKTdRmjmQhaKTdRupc6AdRTc0maXOhjqSkzRmj2ghaSjNGaXtGA4HjmjdTM0Zpc7AfmkyabmjNLmYDs0lJmjNFwHUlNzRmlcB1FNzRmi4DqM03NGaLgOzRTc0ZouA6im5ozRcB1FNzQaTlZXAazsfu8CooWd5gC7EDkjNTNUduMSv9K5eZ82rOhJWLJNNNKabUTlchCMARg01CR8p59DSk0meaVOfKymrofmjNMJO7GPrS5zXcpJmLTQ7NJmmk4BPpRmi4h2aM03PNGaLgOzRmm5pVG44ouAuaVTzz0pWjI6d6aylR7VWqAkcjHFMHJwKjzS5pc1wuPPBwaM0zNGaLgPzS5qPNLmi4D80uajzS5p8wx+KKZuPrSbqPrC7DHnofpUOafmjNZTqcwmMzRmn5ozUXENz7Gjn0P5U/NGaLgM59D+VHPoafmjNFwGc+ho59DT80ZpgIHZRgD9KrytIzbYjnHGBxg9eTVnNJgbs0733GVBHcn7wjBHq2f6UbLgH+D/vqruaM0rIRQZJ2BDIjD/foSObAAREA9Xq/mjj0FFugeRSaKYgjenPuatFqdhfQflRtX+6KErAMzS5pdi+lHlr70wEzRml8seppPL/2v0oAM0ZpPLb1FGx/b86AFzS5pm1/7tGG/umi4D80ZqPP1/Kk3UXAlzRmo91GaLiuSZozUeaXNO4XH5pc1HmjNFx3JM0ZqPNGaLgSZozUeaXNFwH5ozTM0Zp3AfmjNMzRmi4D80ZpmaM0XAfmjNMzRmi4D80ZpmaM0XEPzRmmZozRcB+aM0zNGaLgOzRmm5ozRcB2aM03NGaLgOzRmm5ozRcB2aM03NByACehouA7NGaZmjNFwH5ozTM0ZouA/NJmm5ozRcB2aM03NGaLgOzRmm5ozRcB2aM03NGaLgOzTXPI9uaM0ZpPUCQnPNRR8TfUU4HjFROdvzehzXJJNM6I6osmmk0m7IyOlITUDSAmmk0E00mgpIlLZKN6g5p+0OOevrVdBxk/h9KmQ1vCd3qQ4kb7s7W7UmTnrT5Tl6ZmtU7mDVmAyCT3pc5NJRTEOzQG2nNNpV5ZR700wJlkJbB7DJprzb1wBimRgsrn14pWjIFW3JoYmaM01mBxtXbQOajd2QJX2FzS5pv40ZptNbg01uOzRmoXfDY9KA9axgram0aV1dk2aXNRRtmMH607NZPRmLVnYdmjNMzRmsBD80ZpuaM0APzRmmZozQA/NGaZmlzTAdmjNRGUB2B6Bf1p+4ZAzyelFwH5ozUUrlEyOpPFPzycdqdwHZozTA4Lle4GTS5p3AfmjNMpc0AOzRmm5ozQA7NGabmjNFwH5ozTM0FsDNFwH5ozTc0Zp3AdmjNMByM0uaLgOzS5plLmi4Ds0celNzRRcYu1T/CKTy09KM0ZoEJ5S+p/Ok8r0Y/lTs0uaAGeU3ZhTfLceh/Gpc0ZoAi2uP4TSfMOqn8qmzRmgCDdRu96sZpMKeqj8qAIM0ual2J/dFJ5Se4/GgCPNGaf5I7MaTyT2b9KAG5ozS+U/qtJ5b+g/A0AGaM0m1/7ppCGHVT+VADs0ZpmcUbqLiH5ozTc0ZouA7NGabmii4Ds0hcA4pB1qDfkknvSbAsKcrS5qKNhtwT3p9CYDs0ZpoII4OaVW2sD6GmMXNGaQ5LkHk+1Rs6DBjzn+LNDdgJc0ZpituUn0pc/nRcQ7NGaTa3900maAHZozTaM89eaLgOzRmm0UXAdmjNNoouA6im0UXAdmjNNoouAjRq7AkEOOAynBqKV2Q7BMJGHJQplsfVen408xlid0r7f7q/L+o5pyARrtjUKo7CjR7lqXKU7TUQ8nlSp5an7jZ/Q1okGqctlHISR8ueoxxSxQTRcLdEJ6bc/zrKUE9jbnjvctbT+FR5DHA+7/Oo3jkc83DEf3Sox+lOCN/z0H4LUezY1Uj1ZNkDrSeZ/d/Oowo7szfWnVUafciVRdBaKbS1rsY3uLRTaKYhaM4IPpSUq7STubbxxQgLEBADDsOR9KdK421BBnOSPlpJEdOpyK15nylX0G55NG7tSDJOByaHiYr6EdCKiDs7lQdnqMZ8c0qSBmwepquz8lWG1vSq8kvl85xjvXQ0pI7fZqcSw8n7xvrStJtjz3PAqmZJCTI0UoQnO7YcVNBIryLIT8ifd/wBpqL6aFNJR0L6rsRV9BilquZyfuilVnPesvZt7nL7CT1bJc0uaZmjNchzD80ZpuaM0wHZpc03NGaAHZozTc0ZpgGwUbBS5ozQAFMnJNATafl4ozS5oAQKRnBxThndyePSjNGaYDs0ZptGaAHZozTc0ZoAdmjNNzRmgB+aaeaM0ZoAMUc4xRmjNAB0AApSScCjNGaYBu4560uabmlzRcB2aM03NIeaLjHMeg96UNk0zFGPei4Dg2SfTpS5qPbTu+aLgOzS5puaM0wHZozTc0ZoAdmjNNzRmgB+aM0yjNAD80ZpuaM0XAdmjNNzRmi4D80ZpmaM0XAfmjg9QPypmaM0XGLtQ/wAI/Kjy0/u0maM0CDyk9x+NMa2UsGDsCOlSZozQAzyeOHOfXFRfY27TD8VqxmjNGgFY2cnaRfyoNtPgDemB2zVnNGaVkGhXjglQnO0g+hp/lP6D86lzRmmAsIKrhlqtPEzSkoj4+g/xqxmjNU5XVmMhihdVLFGPsSB/KnFJBwq/L7cVJu96M0XWwiLypP8AnmaeIWI+dgD2PepEbLck0spXjHWqSVrjsiP7Oez5PuKrokkcpLwMw56EVZzkZ9Kerb/lP4Glo3oFiqFk2gmM59BSIJiSHjIqxkg4PWjNQKxDsf8Auml2P/dNS5ozQFiLY/8AdNGx/wC6akzS5oCxDsf+6aNj/wB01N/CTn8KM0BYh2P/AHTRsf8Aumpc0ZpBYi2P/dNG1/7hqXNGaLhYi2v/AHDRtf8Aun8qlzRmi4WItr/3TRtf+6alzRmi4WItrf3T+VJtb+41TZozRcLEO1v7h/Kja390/lU2aM0XCxDtf+635UhV/wC635VPmjdRcLEkIwoyMcU98EbSOtQByKGct1rZVUlYq4RKIwS+Vwec0yW9QcKu736Uycs+AT0quY8VrFKx0U6cWrsjmlMowY0xnI5PH0qKyTfe4lIYIu4fXNOlIUE5qtmVZBLGMYHf+IUpR91qJ1KCUbROgLjbWHIFS8kVOFOGAHbNI+pPjb5bZPvSQ53mR8Fm65HFY0acou7Jp03HUsoamR88Lz9KfA0LjBiRW+nWrGccDge1aSq8uljGpVs7WK2aM03NGa4jhH5ozTc0UAG/k+maXeM0lLxTAGb5lx0ByaUODnPFJxRgUAKr9Sxxk8CnZGcd6ZgUo4oAfmjNNzS5pgOoptGaYDqM0maM0ALmlzTc0ZoAdmjNNzRmgB1FNzRmgB2aKbRmgB2aM0maM0ALmlzTc0UAOzRmm5ozQMdmjNNzRmgB2aM03NGaAHZpc0zNGaYDs0uabRmgB2aM0zNLmgB2aM03NGaAHZozTc0ZoAdmjNNzRmi4Ds0uaZmjNFwH5ozTM0uaLgOzRmmZpc0XAdmjNNzRmi4Ds0ZpuaM0XAdmjNNzRmi4Ds0ZpuaM0XAdmjNNzSZouA/NGaZmjNAD80ZpmaM0XC5ICSQB1p7IyDKtioA2CCKe8zOuD0q4ySWo7kjAuoYD5uhFR59SB9OaajlGyPxHrTz5cnKtsb0NPSWq3HuJuHYfiaNx9TR5Tf30/Ok2qPvSr+HNTaQtRdx9TSnIOCNp/Q0391/ec/QU4COQ4Dtu/wBqmkA3NGaWTKKFZRk/xVHmpkrOwMkzSZpmaM1NxD80ZpmaM0wH5ozTDkdRSbveh6ASZo3VHupeT0Vj+FK4D80maTa56IatIAIsEY9qqK5hpFbNGacIHPoBQYHHVhSs9wsxuaM07yT/AHx+VHk/7f6UgsxuaN1O8n/bP5UeSP75oCzI25pkkLkKd6gN0qfyV/vNT3iXYiEnitYzkos0jOUVoU1t4kG9gZGHdv8ACqkpLMSeSa0bpBFCACfmPes8gk1vTTtdnXQu/eZRuflAPvViMEEqwwynBFJNAZlmxn90m79f8M1ZWBri0huYeZQu11/vY4/Om5JPUuVW0+VjUJU1dR9y+9UkkRu+COqngirtvGHXOTjtipqpOJFdJxuQZoptLmuE84dmlpmaXNADqM02lzTAdmim5paAHZozTaKAH5ozTaKAHUtNopgOzRTaKAHUUlFAC5ozSZozQAtLmm5ozQA6im5ozQA7NGabmjNADs0ZpuaM0AOzRmm5ozQA7NGabmjNADs0ZpuaM0AOzS5pmaXNADs0ZpuaM0AOzRmm5ozQA7NGabmkZsKTQA/NGabmgHNADs0ZqMN970B4pWYKP6UAPzRmm0ZoAdmjNNzRmgB2aM03NGaAHZozTc0ZoAdmjNNzRmgB2aM03NGaAHZozTc0ZoAdmjNMzRmgB+aM0zNGaAH5pM03NGaAHZozTM0bs9OfpQA/NGaQI56I35YpwhlPYD6mgdmN49KM1KLZu7gfQVNDbqvJJY+9VGLk7D5WVM1JDMsbHd0NWXgjYj5RmkMSoeFX8qvklF3HyjfMW4BTsc4OPSooYWfO7K49qsofm9gKbnvRKV7NjsVvKk74H404RE/xj8qVm5PqDUZkwa0VFNGqpJolFuO7n8BUbEI5C549alilD8Z5FUTJlifUmilC0ncqnT1ZZD1NFtaNW2ryOwqi77YyR1PA+tXkGxFX+6MUV9kFVJIfmjNNzRmuYwuSKu7vTW+UkUgcr0pC3c9TV+615gWF6U2TGDUIcjvTtrv14Fa+0vGyQxOPWnogYZNNKqv3noDoo4yaiMUn7whG+Ukc0oRjQsg3YVcZqcHIqoU4y6jIeI+vLegphPOW6+lOmPvUWaibs7IVxZv3yAEcjpVCSN1bCxsx9hV3NLuG0jHPrTjWktzSFVx0IrWAQxMsmC8nL/4VX0wmPz7dusb5q5mqZ/dasD2mT9f8io5nK9yHJt3ZcZEcguisR3IBp2aZmjNRdiuyhmlptFIzH0ZptGaAH5opuaM0wH5opuaWgB1GabRmgB2aXNNzRmgB2aXNMzS5oAdmjNNzRmgB2aM03NGaAHZozTc0ZoAdmjNNzRmgB2aM03NGaAHZozTc0ZoAdmjNNzRmgB2aM03NGaAHZozTc0ZoAdmjNNzRmgABIz7ml3c0maM0AKzcj0BzRv68UlFAChuu6lzzjvTeKKAHZoPNNzRmgBcUfjSZozQAYoxRmjNAC88+9KOABTc0ZoAfmkzTc0ZoAdmjNNzRmgB2aM03NGaAHZozTNw9aUBm+6jH6CgB2aM04QTH+DH1NOFrJ3ZR9OaY7MjzRmpxaL/FIx+nFPFvEOqk/U0D5WVNw9aUEnoCfoKuhEX7qKPwp2aA5SmIpW6Ifx4pwtpD1KirWaTNA7IhFr/ekP4CnC3jHXJ+pqTNGaB2QgijXoi/lTs46cU3NFADs0maTNJmgLjs0oYjpTM0Z7mmgJN5zntSM5br0pUTdyeTS+X8wxxiteWbQDc4T3b+VNzQzbmJ7dqbWcn0QEc6N99OT3X1FVS4Zcg1baZE+835c1RuZI3YvGsiv3IAwfrXRSlLZo6qLls0NE5jkDehqBJlZsBgaktIhd3DCVSEjxlfUn+laclrbPFtaFAPYYxROtGErG0qii7WKUDK84djhIv1arLXQ/hFZi5jkeHOQhwD7VZStOVS1YnTT1ZZE7n0qdW3LnpVVSBVhOF571lWjFROetGKQ/NDAgA4NOixyx7UM5qYUuaN2YxjccMRLk8saZvLH5jhfQUjMGwSeRUbHB6j8KpRfPy9ClH3rE4kH93io2xuOOlNU5poOcn3qq6XKVOKSH5pwlYCo80ma5E2tjAeWJOTSZpuaTNK4D22hvlbIow23dj5fWiJPMbGcAUSoYiF3Eqe1Vy6c3QYmaqX52m3l/uPj/P5VYzVe/8Ams29iDSjuItNwTSZpobcqn1UH9KTNSBUoptLTJFpabRQA7NLTaKAHZpc02jNADs0ZpuaXNADs0ZpuaM0APzRmm5ozQA7NGabmjNADs0ZpuaM0AOzRmm5ozQA7NGabmjNADs0ZFNzUjzB4EjCAFe9NANzRmm5ozSAdmjNNzRmgB2aM0zNLmgB2aM03NGaAHZozTM0ZoAfmjNMzRmgB+aM0zNGaBD80Zpm4etJvHY5+lAyTNGaaA7fdRz9FNOEMx6RN+PFAWYZozTxazn+FR9Wp4spO7oP1osPlZDmjNWBYj+KU/gtPFnEOpdvxosHKypmk3D1FXhbQD/lmD9eakVUX7qKPoKdh8pnAlvuqx+gp4imbpG348Vf3UZoHyopi1mPXav1NPFmf4pB+AqxmjNAWRCLSMdWc/jini3hH8AP15p+aTNAxwCr91QPoKXNMzRmgLjs0ZpuaTNAD80mabmjNAh2aTNJRmgBc0ZpuaM0AOzRmm5ozQAuaM03NLQk2AE4FNL/AJ0kp/dk+lVw/NdNGKcTopQUlcto28AjvQTn+lQ2rZiOT0LUhm5wn51n7NttIz9m22kXo3GKWRwIyfXgVTViRz1qaXgRj0FW5SimmS7rRjaimZui0/NNYdxWdJpS1HTaUtSqUPeopOBVl1kb7qH8eKZ9kGC07ZA/hXp+ddTnFHaqsVuylFcmCdmAJRhhsdqsSanHt4fPsOtRyAHoAPYdqqOh81Qq5YnpUSpRk7s1cU/eZPB8ztJIDlznAPStGOGFlyrMfxrPi5UEVZikKmrlFtWTsRVg2vdZcVET7q8+tOzTQ24ZFFcUr31PNle+o4MRnHek3AjIpKY+Ou7B962pVGtGaU5W0FL4pjPzmonkyQi/fY4FWEsIiuXZ2b13YrWdSMGmzpfKtWNLnbhfvNwKlAAABGAO+aqkNBcmMsWyMqx649KlUk07KpZ9CZQ5iXC+pprDH0NOUU4jK44/GplRi1oZSpq2hGqlz8ooZSh+YVNbkISpPIPWi6ccAVjGldb6mUY3diNPMQ5XHPY02R2dvn4I7UB6Y7Zb8KupT5Y6M0nT5VdEkUioW3LuzVW7P+iSfh/OpM1Beti2I9WFc6d7IwJoz+5j/wBwfypc00fKir6KBRmpe4FWlpKKYhaKSloAWim5o3D1FMB1Lmmg5Bxzjk0DJ6Bj+FFgHZozQEkPSNz/AMBNKIZj/wAsX/KiwCZpc077NcH/AJZH8xTvslx/cA+rCiw7MjzRmpRZz/7A/wCBU77DL/fj/WiwWZBmjNWPsL95V/BaUWPrN+S0WDlZWzRmrQsV7yt+AFO+wxd3kP4iiwcpTzRmrv2OD/bP1al+yW/9wn6saLBylDNGa0fs1uP+WS0ohhHSFP8Avmiw+Uzdw9RSbx6itZY4sE7EB/3RS5A7D8qdrBymVzgHa2D0OOtADHojH/gJrWLkjGKTcfWhpdA5UZnlyn/llJ/3yaUQTn/li1aW4+tGaQWRnC2uD/yyx9SKd9kn/uqP+BVezRmgLIpfYpj3jH40osZe8iD86uZozQOyKv2Fu8y/980v2Ed5j/3zVnNGaAsiuLFO8jn8qcLKEdWc/wDAqmzRmgNCIWlv/cJ+rGnC3gH/ACyX8admjNAAI4x0jQf8Bp+cdMUzNGaB3H7qTNNzRmgLjs0ZpmaM0CuOzRmm5ozQA7NGabmkzQA7NGabmjNADs0ZpuaM0CHZpM03NGaAHZozTc0ZoAdmjNNzSZoAdmjNNzRmgB2aM03PIz0oYgsdowKAFzRmm5ozQIdmjNNooAcDzTHYilqNkf8AgYH2auilUSVmb0pxWjGNcYyG5U8GqaykyEIGfHXapNOuSyAhkw3YA5rQsfLjs4tmPmXcT6mqqTUFddTruoK8epnxXGYQgPclvxNTowAqG9ZTeqy9WB3Y71YgaEdmDf3jzVxleN0hvSN0iZAdpLcZ7VNKcpG47jFRZ70+N1wY3+6e/pXNzOTal1PPk23qNozTnjeP3X1FRg56c/Soaa0IHZqOY4jqdYHYZJC+1RzRMoAYjJ6YrWnBqSbRrTVpK5QIyag6ahb+zg1aciPr+VQNEY7i3Zx87HLD056V0TdkdlaaULdyWeH7PIXUfuWPP+wf8KcADgirhK5P3h9RmoRaxA5TOPRW/pWUKtlZmNPEWVpD4xhaljTexz0HWmbSF+6QKfDIEYhuAe9Z3Uql5GEnzTuxCSenAph4qaQbeR0quxJOOn1rrbUUdKaSIJnMZSQDOw5xVhb1CmQwqMxjIGeT3NU5oYxlmTG3rWU6SqWZouWRN5huLkMPuoOtWegqCHGwbRxVhSOh6VfI1G0WKadvdJSmxUJbO6ms2KJ2L7OMKBjj1qAyEHa/XsfWlGd3yvcypyu7PckZw3XqO9RO2DUTsQcDvUDXAY4G47Rg4GabilLmNlSXMpF1GyKRDuBb1PH0qqsvmKEjblup/uirQaNQAOQOAKmonJcqIrRcvdiKTVe6+eSGP1OashyeigfhTXhBcTYwyjH1rH2LirnPKi4q4pPJptFJmucwJ/sMP9+Q/jTvsUHo5+rVLmkzVFDBaW4/5Z5+rGl+zW4/5YrTs0ZoGKIoR0ij/wC+aUBB0RR+ApuaUEZGenemFx4bHTFKSeoJwajcru+TpTomGSp6Gn1sFxdx9aN1NcbD7U3NTsFx+aM0zNGaAuPzSngZHQ1HmnRuM7T0NNdguODYINIW3En1pHUofamjJOByaNdguPzRmmEkHB4NJmkK5JmkzTM0oOenWgLjs0ZpmaM0BcfmlB5FR5ozQFy2duyq+aZuPrRmrlLmC4/NJmm5pM1AXH5ozTM0ZoC4/NGabmkzQA/NGaZmjNAXH5ozTM0ZoAfmjNMzRmgB2aM03NGaBDs0ZpuaTNAD80ZpmaM0APzSZpuaM0AOzRmm5ozQA7NJmkzRmgBc0uaZmjNADs0ZpuaM0AOzRSBSwJAzjrSZoAdmkzSZozQAuaM02jNAh2aVVLttGKQPhCmByc5p0MfmsecAU0ruwwT5iUbjPQ+hprZU4bg0s0flNjP0qdGWWLJUFsYqlG+jGVs0ZpvI4PUUZqCR2aZK+0YHX+VLmgqMlq2oxUnqb0Yxb1KjrgE45NV185FPlyFUPIGM1daPzW54Tv7024HIxwMYre8ZPlO2NSLlymcu8T/Nl2arcZ3jKnNQ3CFUWReGRgQau+XFcKswBRmGSVOOaJTUNwqVlTdnsPty/mBVPJ4q6YVA+ZgW/wB0VVtE8q4UtIzZBHIAq0zZJNNOM9Tmk41HdEe+SAgArt7ccU4TB+qYI54PFIWBBU9DUIO0kVnyuMl2M+RqS7FjeSeTSSbnAVQWI5xUatmmM53EqSMelaVGlF3NKiSQEFDlk2n1Iqrd83Nv/n+Kri3Uo43B/Yiql2yyXttgBOmcf71cqSezOYtE8mhThwT2pZY2iOW5U9GFRnkVK92SuEdHqTmTBqNsZ46GoDJlTngjgimicbTzz2rqqR5onZOlzRuiwhAPHWpCQ64NVI33H6VJFJufOflHA9zVWjFWY5QUFZhJ8xNJcwtdWbtEMzqpBH97j+dPb1qBbkw3Hmg/ulwr/j/hTlohz0jcIv8AUxOASPLXd7cdasAZHFWZf3cbvGo3NySP51TiU4Ow4A7dqzhP7LMadT7LJSP3TZPAGarySApsCbh3yepqR9zLtJwKhcYFaOCbuzdU4t3ZVcO0iRnhXYLnPIrdjChflGPWsCUsxwn3gcg+lWI9UMJBlRv9rHNY1Yt2tsVVg2tB2oqiXCSR4Bc4bHf3pI6s31p9o2XEB3Y+baP4h6j3qvHhl4AqoXjHuKM0oEymleUFCqnOarzH9y/5UkIxCg9s1nOteOhy1K3MtCSkpKK5jnLuaM0zNGaoB+aM0zNGaAH5ozUeakeNkVWJGGotcYZoz6U1WAcFhkDqKWR1ZyUGBR0uBOHDr83eoWypwaarY+lSMrFPmGPQ1fxIVxuaM0zNPUhosN2NSlcB6xsVzTD6Gp451VdrYqB/mYsvPtVyiraDdiZHDrhuT3qP5kcFOaiDEEEdqtQOp57fyoj7wELFixLdTTc1NdMvGKr5qZqzsDHZozTc0makRYwJV3Lw46j1qLPOD1pquUYMP/11YbZMm4cH1qviHuRKC3SnFGFSW2FIDdalmIABGMg1oqacbjtoR/Zvlzk1XOQSD1FTfa12Y5/Kq5bJJP1qZ8v2ROw7NGaGjZI1ckYNMzWbVhD80ZpmaM0APzRmmZozQA/NGaZmjNAD80ZpmaM0APzRmmZozQA/NJmm5ozQA7NGabmjNADs0ZpuaM0AOzRmm5pM0APzRmmZpyOUbcuM+9CAXNJmm5ozQA7NGabmjNIB2aM0igscKMmkOVOGGDTswHZ/WjNMzT9xMOBH3zvoWoBmjNMzRmkA7NGabmjNMB2ackjRnK0kUbSnjoKlW2bzAGPy1UYy3Q9SJ5Gkbc3WnRSbH9j1pbmEQkbTwahzQ7p6iLMq7xuX7w6j1qvmpEkJHuKbKP416Hr7Gh66gNHJwOTRmkDbSD6HNSzKCSy9e49aSQEeaa671wOoozRmnCXK7lwm4SuRNHl0XHAYE/Skt/3UskB6feWps1Bc/JsnHVDz9KuU+dlVKntGWKkWXHDfnTRGxG4/KDyM9aCg9SadOM46pBTjNaoc59Kg8xmbCIzkddo6Uk+5ImZWHT0q9b7I4wi9AK1q1ORLQ627LYprKclMFZP7rcfjUqqigfxn3puospVGH3lYYoWnCSqK7QnHmV2Thj24HtTZoRMoLD505Vu/FAOKinu1VliTl34z2Aq5NJamc7JDt7xx7VOQeSDULM30+lP835cYqN/MZSyxkqOp44qYuDRdN02uhXnaTIK7WYnbjpmriaXEyfvJJGfuVOB+FUJo5eDlQQcjnNWE1VQu1gVb0xWdXmsuTY2lF2XJsRlDFO0Ej5VcHK9WH9Ksq6YACnHaqil55nlYYJ4A9qspx1rRJNLm3FKMX8W48qrjjd9M1DcAC2IAwMjirIZQMmqtxzA31BP51lVtdWOSto0kX7Vytrb+8Y61HKDGyuv+r6Y9KjBMcFo4/wCeVT7gwweVapb10MG7MhaXI4qJoyy72OVzg47UrqY3Kn8D6ipbV8GRTyCM4pe1k9Gae2lYhMZKlY1HyjO0VSmGUJrQkzDMsqfd7j+lFzAl0hKEI5HDdj9a6FJJLsdcaygl2ZFpV0UVIJTw4DRn69qs3EHzGSMfN/Eo7+9UfIYQRxuNkkY4/wA+lXba585dj8TJ1B71nzdUYOf24/MrzjzLdmUcjk/Smp/q0+gq1Io2yMq5baflHeqcR/dJ9Kzq2eqMqkoy1Q+ikorEzLOaM03NGaBDs0ZpuaM0AOzRnpyeOlNzRmgCxbIJH+apLqJUXcOtVFdkOVNLJM0n3jWilHlt1HfQM1M9yzxhcAe9Vs0ZqYyaEyV+RvHfrQh+8PUUxG5wehoHyuM1TVncSdxxOaA1RngkelGaHpqJMkJDdeD60BijfzFR5oDcYPIotfVBfuTN6g5BpmaQNt91NIwxyPumi1x7Ds0+NxtKOMjtUOaM1OzGSsmOVO4frSJIUORyD1FND0pYN16+tO3VCuT7uMqcrUcjv0PT1qMMYz6g/kacSCuV5X09Ke6sO4gyTgdamWEkdzUUeNxPtWnGBt4qqdPm3KirmdIjIOpwOx7UzNXbkAEfXFZ4NTUjysTVh+aM0zNGazEPzRmmZozQA/NGaZmjNAD80ZpmaM0APzSZpuaM0AOzRmm5ozQA7NGabmjNADs0ZpmaXNADs0ZpmaM0APzSkMFDFSA3Q1HmlLkgAsSB0HpTGSL5e1t7EMPuj1puas2kUTxbmAJPXNVZQFlZV6CqlGyTCw7a2zftO31puaXz38nysjbTM1Lt0As2syxMd/Q96S5mWWQFegqvmkzVcztyhfoPJq7HcRCDBIBA6Vn5ozRGTjsCdh+eTRmmZozUiH5ozTM0ZoAt2kyx5Vjin3NyOPLPzfnVHNGav2jSsVclaSSZucsfQUH5IiHiIYnhqsWUalAT35NWJo129OvWrVNtcw7GarYNSqwyQ3Q8VXPBI9DilB4rOL6GbHMNrFTUm7KofbH5Uxvnjz/EtNQ5jPsc00rMOgr9cikV9p6ZHcHvRmmHg0pK2oJk7R/LviO5PTuKS32vOgYAjrg+tRxymNsjkHqKmdQ2JIzhuoYUR3uVezLEqkuSaibAqOS/IKpLCcn+JTUbzM3bFdbqxSOpVYpCyfNleuariSe3GAN6joasIMR7jyTTHHBp2U1qjohLmVyJA87BpeFHIWrW3cOGINVbV9wbPZ2UVbHFNRjayCVpoibIbDZz71A//H2nsBV8p5qbT97+E1nk/wClA+39K5ZwcWcM4OLJ81IkmyCRccORUOaeAGhHscGiiryHRSc9SB8tVVQWlLfwhtv49aszNhGCckdT6U2KLFrsH3id3410TmondOsoNIkj4NTNwfY8io0xIoYVJJwiZ65NTVinG5niUnHmG5plycWoH947j/If1pc027OYYz/sD9M1zROFFuUf6BaH0UD9Kjjfjb+VTyr/AMS2P/ZVDVMHBzVVNJBJFlx5seP416e9QwtiVD2PH505XwQwpky4bevRufxpNdSEyYnOQenSoVcxOwcgR9jUjnLZ/vDNRyr5kZUde1Xd2sNSaTj0ZMxDDawyP5fSoHQoQ45APyt3FNgc+Wob6c1KGx0qbXFdxZKknmrkcOOo9feopE3fMvXuPWm7fmDRcMP4f8KckgmUleJF+8tFr7h5ohzSVI67uR1qOs2rDTuT0UlFSAtFJRTAWikooAWikooAXNJmkooADTt29f8AaH60xskcdRTQ2e9ax95CsSufmB9RTc0hOVX8aaTjrVWCxJnPFN3YODwf51CZNrBvzFSsBInB91NT8L8h2HBiDxTlYdB0PVf8KqLIR1p4kBq7BYmPB60ZpnmA9Tz60hYYpONwsS0ZqNG3A+xp2ay1iwaHhsUA4OVOD6GoXJT5l5HcelIJQa0SvqKxZzg71GCOq1Ml0AvXH1qoJOnOcfmKPcVSuh7bE8s+/ofx9KhzTS1AORkVlNPqPcdmjNNzRmoAdmjNNozQA7NGabmjNADs0ZpuaM0AOzRmm5ozQA7NGabRmgB2aM03NGaYDs0ZpuaM0AOzRmmZozQA7NLmmZozQA8MV+6SPoaSm5ozQA7NGabmjNADs0ZpuaM0AOzRmm5ozQA7NJmkzSZoAfmkzTc0ZoAfmkzTc0ZoAsQXBh4IJGeMdqklvdy4TJPqRjFU80ZqlNpWHcdQDg03NGakRKrbWyKUYEnH3XBAqHdjr0pQ2CCOxzW2+orDwaD0pp+8frTWbsKdrisOzTo5Nh/2T1FQI/O38qfmsmrMonmjWVMH6hh2qE54DdaVHx8p6fyp7DIwae5OzHTLslO3gGmPKBExPUU+SUSL83D1Ea6Oaz02N1UdOXu7EFr/AKk+7E1dilBG1utVgoXIXgZpayVRwkwjVcWXw6Rjcx4H61mk5usnqeadTG/160Tqc4TnzslzVlONMnb1b/CqtXokU6XhiNvLN+Bzipp7maKFxwkcI4JO5vqad9KiDGSdnbr/AFp+amTBjhw24cE/rSlixyTk0ylpcztYbk2rMWo7hv8ARtp6hsj6Y5p9RXH+qpx3EjWm/wCQef8Armv9Kzq0b3CWjL/uqKzauruNj1PanggqUbof0NQ0b/WlF30IsSg/u1z1BK0Zpgbg89xSbhV2FYV8bvrSeYR97p61G7Z+tOVgw/nUtcupViQNnpSnBkD/AHZB/EO/1qqTsYjNPEtXYLFhj83TB64/wpjDPPemCUdKPMX1pWuKxPRRRXMMSjNFFABmiiigAooooASiiimAU1lDdevqKKKL2AYY3/hYH600pKOw/OiitIzYCeVIf4f1p8aSoecbT2zRRTlJjHGNCclBn1pPJT0b86KKzUmITyU9WpREn+0fxooo55dwHDAGAMCjNFFIBc1F5A7Mw+tFFNSa2ATyj2f9KXy3/vj8qKKrnkMXY3dx+ApwAUYFFFJybELmiiipATNGaKKADNFFFABmjNFFABmjNFFMAzRmiigAzRmiigAzRmiigApM0UUAGaKKKACjNFFABmjNFFABmjNFFABmjNFFABmjNFFABSUUUAGaKKKADNGaKKADNGaKKBhmkxzwcGiimm1sAmHPTBppD+lFFaKTAPLc9v1p43AfNjNFFTJ3AXNPEmBhunrRRUrcTHHDCm54oorVbkoaxAGTUYkw2G6HoaKKbV0Wh+ahmYrLER3OP1oorOO41uTHrQGChz6oQKKKlbiGx8J9admiih7gFFFFIQZpk3KAUUU1uNE8txJMFEjAgeg6mo6KKG77gFFFFIBpUepFNZSBndRRVqTAAhIByBmlCYOd/PsKKKHNgPzSYHoPyooqLgJtX+6KXaB2FFFVdgf/2Q==');}
```

```html
<div class="fon">
  <div class="vidos">
  <br><br>
  Я видосик.<br>Посмотри на то, как я<br>привязан к фону контейнера!<br><br>Поизменяй размер контейнера<br>в консоли!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: мне нужно удерживать блок строго в одном месте background при любом изменении ширины браузера. не буду же я писать тысячи медиа запросов? или я что-то не так понял?

Comment: зачем тысячи? ваше решение будет зависеть от того, как вы позиционируете фон. если фон привязан к `top` и `left` с помощью свойства `background-position` (либо просто по умолчанию стоит), то все просто - позиционируете ваше видео относительно блока с фоном. При любой ширине экрана будет нормально. Если у вас фон, к примеру, привязан к середине блока (и при изменении размеров экрана уходит за ег определы с обеих сторон), позиционируете тоже посередине, сдвигаете влево (отрицательным маргином, трансформом. калком), и радуетесь. Медиазапросы даже не понадобятся.

Comment: Добавил код в ответ.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! всё получилось!)

Comment: @ДмитрийМакаревич Пожалуйста, не отвечайте фразой "спасибо". Вместо этого проставьте галку у ответа, который вам помог больше всего.

Comment: есть косяк, при уменьшении масштаба браузера видео теряет координаты

Comment: Ну звыняйте, косяки браузера исправлять версткой - неблагодарное занятие. А то, что масштабирование вв браузерах реализовано трансанально - факт.

Как насчет запретить масштабирование как мракобесие и саботаж?